# Why won't this match text work by copying not only the text but the color as well?

Tags: autocad, autolisp

I have been modifying this code but somehow it only works to copy the source text but ignores the source text's color.

```
(defun c:matchTextAndProp (/ cEnt ss textColor)
(vl-load-com)
(if (and (setq cEnt (car (nentsel "\nSelect Source Text: ")))
         (member (cdr (assoc 0 (entget cEnt)))
               '("TEXT" "MTEXT" "ATTRIB")))
(progn
  (setq textColor (cdr (assoc 62 (entget cEnt))))
  (redraw cEnt 3)
  (if (setq ss (ssget '((0 . "TEXT,MTEXT"))))
    (foreach x  (vl-remove-if 'listp
                  (mapcar 'cadr (ssnamex ss)))
      (entmod (subst (assoc 1 (entget cEnt))
                     (assoc 1 (entget x))
                     (entmod (subst (cons 62 textColor) (assoc 62 (entget x)) (entget x)))))))
)
(command "_regenall")
(princ))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the color of an entity is ByLayer (256), the 62 group code may be omitted.

```
(defun c:matchTextAndProp (/ cEnt elst text color ss i)
  (if (and (setq cEnt (car (nentsel "\nSelect Source Text: ")))
           (member (cdr (assoc 0 (entget cEnt)))
                   '("TEXT" "MTEXT" "ATTRIB")
           )
      )
    (progn
      (setq elst  (entget cEnt)
            text  (assoc 1 elst)
            color (cond ((assoc 62 elst))
                        (T '(62 . 256))
                  )
      )
      (redraw cEnt 3)
      (if (setq ss (ssget '((0 . "TEXT,MTEXT"))))
        (repeat (setq i (sslength ss))
          (setq elst (entget (ssname ss (setq i (1- i)))))
          (entmod
            (subst text
               (assoc 1 elst)
               (if (assoc 62 elst)
                 (entmod (subst color (assoc 62 elst) elst))
                 (append elst (list color))
              )
            )
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
  (command "_regenall")
  (princ)
)
```